# Ipv4 properties tab greyed out

Tags: windows-8.1, network-adapter, ipv6, ipv4

I am facing this problem of IPv4 and IPv6 properties tabs greyed out and not able to change the settings of the same. I have tried many solutions given online such as netsh commands and antivirus and malware scans. I have also replaced tcpip.sys file from a healthy system.But the problem still exists. Please post the solution if anyone has.

Comment: Are you using cmd to find your IPv4 ? And IPv6 ?

Comment: nope I tried resetting IPv4 and IPv6 using netsh winsock reset and netsh interface ipv4 reset commands. There is a IP address thats why the ingternet is working but i cannot change or modify it using the properties tab of IPv4

Answer (score 1):

**Using Registry**

1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then press ENTER.
2. Locate and then click the following registry :

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network

3. Right-click this key, click Export, and then save the file.
4. Click the Network key again, and then delete the Config entry. The Config entry will be reconstructed when you restart the 
   computer.
5. Restart the computer. You may have to manually turn off the computer.